# Good online grammar checker

Tags: discussion

I tried  `grammarly and prowritingaid.com`.   They are good, but sometimes they miss things. 
In a long text, I was surprised they didn't mark `its` as error. Are there any other good alternatives?

Comment: Do you want to learn English or do you want to learn grammar? There is a distinct between the two. Not knowing this is a common problem for Non-English speakers.

Comment: @GWarner care to elaborate?

Comment: Yes. Could you please elaborate. I want to learn English in general. But isn't grammar part of it

Comment: This isn’t worth an answer, but I don’t think there are any really good grammar checkers online. Probably the best thing you can do is learn the rules, and keep to things you know are right, I’m afraid.

Comment: "Its" is a correct term for the possessive of "it."  In context, it could be the correct thing and "it's" an error.

Comment: grammarly etc are about as good as you are going to get. NLP is hard, and grammarly etc are systems based on rules. It can become confused. It can flag errors that don't exist (for example it thinks that "confused" should be "confusing" in the previous sentence. And it can miss things. For example, it doesn't complain about starting a sentence with "and". They are tuned to catch the errors that native speakers make.  Grammarly is usually good at spotting the incorrect use of "its" but as its context-dependent,  it can miss some.  It missed the incorrect "its" in the previous sentence.

Comment: (Yes I did write that comment in a particular way to catch out Grammarly)